# Non-base64 string is treated like it is

Tags: go, base64

Good day!

I have a base64-encoded id that is some path like "/some/path/ok"

```
L3NvbWUvcGF0aC9vaw==
```

When I try to decode it - it is ok as it should be.

Sometimes I get some wrong data into my function, for example:

```
5b835b45b2de7748459a1183
```

It is not base64-encoded string, but my code and golang decoder says it is ok:

```
s, err:= base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString("5b835b45b2de7748459a1183")
```

Is there any way I can ensure that given string is or not a base64? Or I have to rely on some other tools like checking path after decoding?

Comment: What makes you think `5b835b45b2de7748459a1183` is not base64? All characters are in the base64 set. It's not go's fault (or any other library) that you're passing a hexadecimal representation, it just decodes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`5b835b45b2de7748459a1183` is a valid base64 string, so you can't do anything about it. There is an input data whose base64 encoded form is exactly this.

This has nothing to do with Go or processing the base64 string, this is most likely a fault in the source that generates this text. This is most likely a hex representation of some data (optionally with other transformations). You have to fix your source if it generates anything other than base64, or you have to use the proper decoding algorithm (not base64 in this case).

Answer (score 1):

No. The correct way to check if the string is base64 is using the error of the `DecodeString` method, as it'll fail if it's not base64. It is also the go way to do things.

It's important to notice that the string can be a base64 string and don't have the information that you need (as it seems to be the case here). In that case I suggest you to sanitize your result before using it (checking if it's a valid file/folder would do the trick).